# RegEx for only alphanumeric characters except ONE occurrence of another char

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following pattern for only alphanumeric characters.

```
/^([0-9]|[a-z])+([0-9a-z]+)$/i
```

how can I add to it a pattern which allows for only ONE occurence of the '=' chatacter?

Comment: That's a redundant regex. `/^([a-z0-9]+)$/i` accomplishes the same thing. You don't need the `[0-9]|[a-z]` part, because the second part means the same thing.

Comment: `([0-9]|[a-z])+` == `[0-9a-z]+`

Comment: Should it match these strings: `=123`, `123=`, `=`?

Comment: @Welbog: You'd need a `{2,}` instead of the `+`, but yeah.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @georg no it shouldn't have leading and trailing = if there is a pattern for that , id appreciate it. I just did custom string manipulation for that part

Comment: If you pay a little more attention here *alpha, numeric, and alphanumeric* you will know OP's wrong in the first place let alone thinking about his/her regex critically. @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @revo: ?? The regex does indeed only match strings with alphanumeric characters in them. Two or more, to be precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/^[a-z0-9]+(=[a-z0-9]+)?$/i
```

this will match strings like `123abc` and `123abc=def`

If the `=...` part is mandatory, then

```
/^[a-z0-9]+=[a-z0-9]+$/i
```

Comment: I want to only match 123abc=def324 and not just alphanumeric. It needs to be key value pair with = as the delimeter

Comment: Any way if a space is entered before or after the "=" for it to be ignored?

Answer (score 0):

Here your regex, but you didn't specify your pattern, so it's hard to understand really what you want to achieve. 
Supposing you don't care about the order that's the one:

`([a-z0-9])+(=){0,1}`

this one check for the presence of 1 or more a-z 0-9 chars and for the presence of 0 or 1 = symbol

If you want the = at the end and chars at the beginning you can change as below:

`^([a-z0-9])+(=){0,1}$`

If you want it in the middle and then chars again here is the one:

`^([a-z0-9])+(=){0,1}([a-z0-9])+$`